# Search for a one-hot encoded label in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have an `ndarray` called `labels` with a shape of `(6000, 8)`. This is 6000 one-hot encoded arrays with 8 categories. I want to search for labels that looks like this:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

and then tried to do like this

```
np.where(labels==[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

but this does not produce the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) along the second axis:

```
np.where((labels == [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).all(1))
```

---

See with this smaller example:

```
labels = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], 
                   [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0], 
                   [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])

(labels == [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

array([[ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Note that the above comparisson simply returns an array of the same shape as `labels`, since the comparisson has taken place along the rows of `labels`. You need to aggregate with `all`, to check whether all elements in a row are `True`:

```
(labels == [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).all(1)
 #array([False, False,  True, False])
```